# outputting all the elements of an array to a file in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I made a small program that asks the user how many items ( variable y) he wants in his order, then asks the user to input the name of each item and the price for each item as well.

But all the txt files created by this code only print the first item name and the first item price.

How should I correct this?

I already tried creating different classes for the customer name and item name\price.

I also tried creating a different array for the items.

```
 #include "Item.h"
#include "Receipt.h"


Item iArray[1000];
Receipt boA[1000];
int loc = 0;
int y;
string array[];
string iName[1000];
void addItem();
void functFix();
void printI();
void p_opt();
int main()
{
    int sel = 0;

    cout << "Welcome\n\n\n";


    do {
        cout << "Please select an option from the menu below:\n\n";
        cout << "1) Add an order" << endl; //need to find a way to make 1) add 2) print 3)exit
        cout << "2) Exit" << endl;
        cin >> sel;
        system("cls");
        switch (sel) {
        case 1:
            functFix();
            system("cls");

            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Bye" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid option" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;




        }
    } while (sel != 2);
    return 0;
}
void addItem()
{
    string itemName;
    double itemPrice;





        cout << "Please enter the item Name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, itemName);
        iArray[loc].setItemName(itemName);
        cout << "Please enter the item Price: ";
        cin >> itemPrice;
        iArray[loc].setItemPrice(itemPrice);





}
void functFix()
{
    string Name;

    cout << "Please enter the customer name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, Name);
    boA[loc].setName(Name);
    ofstream order;
    order.open(boA[loc].getName() + ".txt", ios::out | ios::app); //trying to make customer name to be file name so that  a new file is created once the order is put in place
    order << setw(30) << "MONTILLATECH\n" << setw(40) << "382 Via Versalles Villas Reales\n" << setw(33) << "Guaynabo, PR-00969\n" << setw(31) << "787-678-6043\n\n";
    order << "Customer name: " << Name << endl;
    order << "---------------------------------------" << endl;

    order.close();
    cout << "how many items in the order?" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        addItem();
    }
    p_opt();
}
void printI()
{
    ofstream order;
    string filename;

    order.open(boA[loc].getName() + ".txt", ios::out | ios::app); //trying to make customer name to be file name so that  a new file is created once the order is put in place
    order << "Ordered items:\n\n";
    //Need to make a loop that keeps printing items in an array //Array could be of any number but equal to y (y=quantiy of items desired)


    for (loc=0; loc < y; loc++)
    {
        order << iArray[loc].getItemName();
        iArray[loc].getItemPrice();

        order << "Your item name is: " << iArray[loc].getItemName();
        order << " ---------- $" << iArray[loc].getItemPrice() << endl;
        cout << "y: " << y << endl;

    }

    order << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "y: " << y << endl;
    order << "\nTotal: total" << " $" << endl;

    order << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\n\n";
    order.close();
    loc++;
}
void p_opt()
{
    int opt1 = 0;


        cout << "Do you want to print the order?" << endl;
        cout << "1) yes" << endl;
        cout << "2) No" << endl;
        cin >> opt1;

        switch (opt1)
        {
        case 1:
            printI();
            break;
        case 2:
            exit;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid option" << endl;
        }

}
```

Program right now only prints the last item of the array. It should print all items stored in the array.

Example of code running:

Please enter the customer name: Test66
how many items in the order?
3
Please enter the item Name: item1
Please enter the item Price: 1
Please enter the item Name: item2
Please enter the item Price: 2
Please enter the item Name: item3
Please enter the item Price: 3
Do you want to print the order?
1) yes
2) No
1

text outputted in the txt file:

### test 382 Via Versalles Villas Reales Guaynabo, PR-00969 787-678-6043

### Customer name: Test66

Ordered items:

item3Your item name is: item3 ---------- $3

Your item name is:  ---------- $0

### Your item name is:  ---------- $0

### Total: total $

Comment: Please reformat your code to create a proper [mcve] . Any commented parts are unnecessary, the rest does not compile. What is `iArray`, `y`,`boa`... ?

Comment: iArray is an array for the items, y (explained in the description) is the quantity of items the user wants in the order and boA is an array where the user name is stored. I will try to reformat code to make it look easier to read, I suspect my proble is in the for loop. Please let me know if I should post full code!?

Comment: Currently there is no way in which i can try to run the above code and see what happens.  What values did you use when you encountered the problem? What were the contents of `iArray`,`boa`. What is `getItemPrice()` returning? For all I know `y==1` and everything works. Obviously the code does not do what you intended so only stating what it should, without showing what it does do, doesn't help.  No, you should not post the full code, create [mcve]. Read that link. You should do more than just copy-paste from your project.

Comment: I have reformatted the description once again. Let me know if you understand my problem now.  I need help asap. And apologies for any inconvenience caused, I am a beginner and I need to finish this program for a lab.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the above mentioned issue by re-structuring and organizing the code in addition to adding a separate array for the item names and the item prices.

I created:

```
Item ItemNameArray[];
Item ItemPriceArray[];
```

My code ( output function) ended up looking like this at the end:

```
void printOrder()
{


    ofstream order;
    string filename;
    double total;

    order.open(NameArray[loc].getName() + ".txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    order << "Ordered items:\n\n";

    for (int t = 0; t < y; t++) 

/*y is a variable for the amount of items user wants in the
order.*/


    {

        order << "Your item name is: " << itemNameArray[t].getItemName();
        order << " ---------- $" << itemPriceArray[t].getItemPrice() << endl;

    }
    order << "---------------------------------------" << endl;

    Item* tot;
    tot = itemPriceArray;
    for (int o=0;o<y;o++)
    total = total + *(tot + o);

    order << "\nTotal: "<<total<< " $" << endl;

    order << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\n\n";
    order.close();
    loc++;
}
```

The following is an example of how the program now outputs to a txt file:

test, 382 Via Versalles Villas Reales, Guaynabo, PR-00969, 787-678-6043

### Customer name: testing 3

Ordered items:

Your item name is: test1 ---------- $2

Your item name is: test2 ---------- $3

Your item name is: test3 ---------- $4

Your item name is: test4 ---------- $5

---

Total: 14$

---

**I was able to find the answer for this issue by reading Starting Out with C++ by Tony Gaddis (8th edition).
Thanks for the comments and the help anyway.**

Answer (score 0):

Following on my comments.

This is still not a

- minimal - Your problem is in writing to a file. It's not relevant how you generate the data. You could have manually added code that fills necessary structures without using user input.
- complete - The posted code still does not compile. I still don't know what `Item` is and I don't have "Item.h" file to find that out.
- verifiable - The input you posted does not match what the code would've generated. E.g. there's no "Welcome"...

example. I doubt you've read the page I linked twice.

Adhering to these requirements may seem pedantic and unnecessary, it's not. The better question you ask the better chance someone is willing to read it and answer it. See other questions that get many comments after a minute or two. Invest some time so that someone else is willing to invest theirs. No many people bothered to read through yours. The purpose of the MCVE is also to help you solve these problems on your own - by understanding what's wrong, what code is at fault and how to explain the problem to others and even to yourself. The code posted after the edit is really different that the one before.

In your case creating the MCVE would very likely solve the problem. The following loop with a global `loc` variable are at fault:

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
{
    //addItem(); expands to:
    //...
    iArray[loc].setItemName(itemName);
    //...
}
```

The loop operates on the same element because the `loc` variable is not changing.  This was not in the first version of your question! Thus overwriting the element with newer entries until the last one is left there. Which is exactly what is printed.
The reason for "Your item name is: ---------- $0" rows is that probably the default constructor of `Item` class is setting name to empty string and a price to zero. Again, that's just a guess as I do not know what `Item` is.

My advice would to be get rid of all global variables. Nothing good can come from them. Your code seems messy (at least as posted here), so take time and divide the program into independent building blocks, make a function for each block. The function then operates only on its arguments. Use passing by reference if needed. If a variable is (is needed to be) passed into all functions then so be it. It's more clear that way and more typing in my opinion helps beginners learn the language. Also to say that stepping through the code with a debugger is important skill would be understatement. You would immediately see that the array elements are being overwritten.